# one product has multiple prices

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have been trying now 2 days and doing research about this but i din't find any solution for this

so i have 3 tables what i want is that if a product is having only single price then show that single price if the product is having multiple prices then show the min price and max price of that product.

so in product id number 2 is having 3 prices.

so if the product is having single price then each product will have their price
if product has multiple prices then display min price $ 19.00 __ $ 26.00 max price.

so how can i do this?? how can i display it on the page???

```
product (id,  price)
         1     1
         2     2
         3     3
product_has_price (product_id, price_id)
                       1         1
                       2         2
                       2         3
                       3         4
                       2         5
price (id,  price)
        1   14.00
        2   19.00
        3   24.00
        4   35.00
        5   26.00
```

thanks if anybody helps

Comment: SELECT MIN(`price`), MAX(`price`) FROM `price`

... AND some joins here :)

Comment: You could use GROUP_CONCAT and group by the product ID. Then in your PHP code split the column on ','. If you have more than one price, display the min/max, else display the single price.

Comment: btw do you need all these tables? :) what about to delete `product_has_price` and `price` and add `product_price` with columns `product_id` and `price`

Comment: Why is there a price field in the product table? What purpose does it have?

Comment: The price is in the price table linked by foreign key, not a good idea, you will face lot of complexities querying, better move the price column to product table.

Comment: i need the price table because some products will have size and each size is having different price and some products are not having sizes they will have only one price

Comment: The proposed duplicate doesn't even mention a difference between single and multiple prices, yet 5 people voted for it?  Did you even read this question or the proposed duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  p.id
,       case 
        when min(i.price) <> max(i.price) then 
            concat('$ ', min(i.price), '__ $ ', max(i.price))
        else concat('$ ', min(i.price))
        end as PriceDescription
from    product p
join    product_has_price php
on      p.id = php.product_id
join    price i
on      i.id = php.price_id
group by
        p.id
```

Comment: Thank you Andomar it is working good but the only thing is that how to name the column of price so that i can display it for the moment it is giving  CASE WHEN MIN(i.price) <> MAX(i.price) THEN CONCAT('$ ', MIN(i.price), '__ $ ', MAX(i.price)) ELSE CONCAT('$ ', min(i.price)) END name of the price column

Comment: You can name a column with `as Name`, added to the answer.